# loop through a firebase database of images and display in list view android

Tags: android, listview, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm trying to create a list view of images in android studio. I uploaded some images i created into the FireBase Storage and placed them into the database. How do iterate through the database and display them in a list view?

Comment: That depends mostly on the format of your database. I recommend reading the documentation on [listening for child events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events). if you can't get it to work from that, share the [code where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a sample snippet of your JSON (as text, no screenshots please).

Comment: You can find inspiration with this demo app Friendly Pix: https://github.com/firebase/friendlypix/tree/d911f6b6cf33efd63fb09dcd53207995cd437841

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend watching [Zero to App](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE&vl=en) and checking out the associated [Android source code](https://gist.github.com/puf/f49a1b07e92952b44f2dc36d9af04e3c).